# how to show data json to 2 different highchart bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, label

im trying to show data in bar highcharts.. the bar highcart should be only 2 bar and both of the bar had data ..

so here the explanation...

i have 2 categories bar chart, and both of categories have a sub categories.

to be clear here is the data of categories :

the first category :

`scategori 1-1, scategori 2-1,scategori3-1`

and here is the second category :

`scategori 1-2,scategori 2-2,scategori 3-2,scategori 4-2,scategori 5-2,scategori 6-2`

**and here is the example that i want to achieve :**

[image]

and both of data comes from this json data :

```
[{
"name": "scategories 1-1",
"color": "#1E4585",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 40,
    "total": 40,
    "data": "1",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 2-1",
"color": "#600AB5",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 40,
    "total": 40,
    "data": "2",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 3-1",
"color": "#0DB9D0",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 20,
    "total": 20,
    "data": "3",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 1-2",
"color": "#0DB9D0",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 20,
    "total": 20,
    "data": "3",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 2-2",
"color": "#0DB9D0",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 20,
    "total": 20,
    "data": "3",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 3-2",
"color": "#0DB9D0",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 20,
    "total": 20,
    "data": "3",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 4-2",
"color": "#0DB9D0",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 20,
    "total": 20,
    "data": "3",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 5-2",
"color": "#0DB9D0",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 20,
    "total": 20,
    "data": "3",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},
{
"name": "scategories 6-2",
"color": "#0DB9D0",
"data": [
  {
    "y": 20,
    "total": 20,
    "data": "3",
    "name": "National",
    "drilldown": "3",
    "next": "level2"
  }
]
},]
```

and when I tried the data json above to the script of highchart . the result is not like what I want..

**here is the result of my try:**

[image]

can someone help me to achieve what I want to achieve or to make the result is same like what Ico want

Comment: Hi @riyan193, What exactly do you want to achieve? Should stacked series be represented by one column and legend? Could you reproduce your current stage in jsfiddle? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: hi ppotaczek thankyou for answer, i modify for you for the example from http://jsfiddle.net/p0vnxsfe/  and can you give the best practice dude  for image chart 
i give the image on top thankyou

Comment: Thanks for the example! However, I am still not quite sure what you want to achieve. Could you describe the wanted result in more detail?

Comment: hi @ppotaczek i'm sorry my example is not clear, i want make chart second image i attach in first question i have 1 label is national and have 2 column chart stacked and more than 1 legend, example label national have first column chart scategories 1-1 until scategories 3-1 and second column chart scategories 1-2 until scategories 6-2, can you suggest for the examle code js and json ? i hope its clear

Comment: hi i edit my achievement in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `stack` property and create two stacks. Example:

```
var series = [{
        stack: 'A',
        ...
    },
    {
        stack: 'B',
        ...
    }
];
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0fbrac5g/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stack